# Run a function on every element of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, tween

I'm new to JavaScript and I would like to run a function on every element of an array.

To be more specific, in my code, I have an `onclick` function. When I click on an element, I want 3 other elements to move. The problem is that only 1 element is moving for each click.

Here is my code:

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(reel);
var intersects1 = raycaster.intersectObjects(rang1);
var intersects2 = raycaster.intersectObjects(rang2);
var intersects3 = raycaster.intersectObjects(rang3);
var intersects4 = raycaster.intersectObjects(rang4);
var inter1 = intersects1.join()
console.log(intersects2)

if (intersects.length > 0) {
    //console.log(intersects1)

    if (intersects[0].object.type === "Mesh") {
        var objinter = intersects1[0].object;
        //DEPLACEMENTS

        new TWEEN.Tween(intersects1[0].object.position).to({
                x: objinter.userData.x0,
                y: objinter.userData.y0,
                z: objinter.userData.z0
            }, 1000)
            .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.Out).start();

    }
};
```

Is it possible to call every element of the array `intersects1` at once, and how would I do this?

Comment: That's the definition of what `map` does. Look up the array's `map` function.

Comment: Where's the click handler? And which array do you want to run the function over?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Sounds like `.forEach` would be more appropriate here.

Comment: @JLRishe If the function acts purely on side effects, ya, it would be. I don't know if he needs any kind of return from the function though, so `map` is more general use. If he's just starting a tween, `foreach` would be a better choice, if he doesn't need any data back that resulted from starting the tween.

Comment: Ok, to be more precise, the element of my array are mesh, and my problem is : on the click, the element intersects1[0] is moved, on another click it is the element intersects1[1] etc... I wanted to now how to make every element moving on one click...

Comment: Why are some parts using `intersects` and some other `intersects1`? I'm trying to write an answer, but I don't understand what you're going for here.

Comment: intersects is used to detect when the mouse is over an element. And intersects1 is the array of the element to move when you click on the intersects element. What i want to know is if it is possible to write something like intersects1[0,1,2] to select many elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `map` (or as @JLRishe, a `foreach` if you don't need to return anything from the loop) would be what you need here. Note a normal `for` loop would work here too, but a higher-order function would probably be the neatest way of achieving this:

```
if (intersects.length > 0) {
    //console.log(intersects1)

    // For each element of intersects1, do...
    // The current object being moved is called obj
    intersects1.foreach(function(obj) {
        if (obj.object.type === "Mesh") {
            var objinter = obj.object;

            new TWEEN.Tween(obj.object.position).to({
                    x: objinter.userData.x0,
                    y: objinter.userData.y0,
                    z: objinter.userData.z0
            }, 1000)
            .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.Out).start();
        }

    })

};
```

Note, I still don't entirely understand why you check `intersects[0].object.type === "Mesh"`, but then do a tween on `intersects1` instead. I ignored that part in the answer. I can update it if you clarify your intent.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am a little bit ashamed... it was so simple... Thank you for your time!

Comment: No problem. Hit the checkmark if this solves your problem to mark the question as solved.